# space tree javascript problem 

Tags: javascript

I am using space tree Java script for creating a organisation chart . now that works fine an all but the problem is i am not able to print the chart properly . i am only able to print the art of the chart which is visible.. and that really doesn't bode well for my project so if anybody can suggest an alternate script for printing or something like that .... it will be really appreciated .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about this, right? http://thejit.org/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

I think you will just have to deal with it by printing less data per page.

Comment: Yep that's it ... any other alternate js library for organisation chart